# Convert hexadecimal color to string (for color blind programmers)

Tags: colors

I'd like to convert a hexadecimal color like `#023abc` to a string representation of the color like `'red'`. Example:

```
'#000000' #=> 'black'
'#ffffff' #=> 'white'
'#00ff2f' #=> 'Yellow'
```

There is no specific programming language required, even a web service is accepted. I know it would be possible for two hexadecimal colors to return the same string representation as they are almost equal. Example:

```
'#00ff2f' #=> 'Yellow'
'#00ff2e' #=> 'Yellow'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to find the nearest color in a table, e.g. [X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names). Distance is simply `(abs(Red1-Red2)+abs(Green1-Green2)+abs(Blue1-Blue2))`